# Half-width inline-block elements cause strange position issues

Tags: html, css, width

I made a small form that has potential to take credit-card details, as part of the Daily UI challenges (#002). I haven't implemented any functionality, just design.

Here is the form I made: http://codepen.io/alanbuchanan/pen/vGZPBp

My questions are regarding the two half-width sections of the form - Expiry Date and CC Number.

Here is the relevant code - this targets the two divs that wrap the two form elements:

```
  div {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 45%;
  }
```

- I wrapped these two sections in their own divs so that I could have more control over their positioning. Is it possible to position these at half-width without these wrapper divs?
- In the example they are taking up 45% width because at 50%, the second div overflows onto the next line.

[image: overflow]

I just want to give it 50% and have it take up half the space as it should. Or should it not?

- Even at 45% width, you can see there is about 1px difference between the height of these two divs.

[image]

After inspecting with Chrome Dev Tools, I can't find the problem behind this.

Any answers to my questions or different approaches to the situation will be very useful.

Comment: I was able to resolve the 1px height issue by using vertical-align:top, but this doesn't get around having to use less than 50% for the width.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases a setup as the following code, could be a best practice when aiming for creation of `inline-block` columns.

```
.column-container {
    font-size:0;
    line-height:0;
}
.column-container .column {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:50%;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:120%;
}
```

**You might wonder, why does the container have zero `font-size` and `line-height`?**

This is often used because some HTML code cotains indented code, like so:

```
<div class="column-container">
      <div class="column">text</div>
```

As of this example, you can see that the container div contains spaces/tabs before the column div is programmed. These spaces/tabs are rendered as characters and so they will obey to whatever the css is telling the characters to do in that container div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox.
Create a outer div having id as `flexdiv` which will contain both the div of expiry and CC number.

Then write following code:

```
#flexdiv
{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 div{
    display:inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:49%;
 }
}
```

[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pywYev)

Here is the guide for flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score -2):

Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqwJMg

Comments: just add `font-size:0` to the form.
These are the changes I made:

```
.minicontainer {
    width:50%;
}
form {
    font-size:0;
}
```

When you add two element inline(50%-50%) you should make sure that the font-size is zero

Comment: In the example pen you posted, the same exact problem remains that I can see; the second div is still 1px higher